# Python read .txt and split words after symbol @

Tags: python, string, split

I have a large 11 GB .txt file with email addresses. I would like to save only the strings till the @ symbol among each other. My output only generate the first line.I have used this code of a earlier project. I would like to save the output in a different .txt file. I hope someone could help me out.

my code:

```
import re 

def get_html_string(file,start_string,end_string):
    answer="nothing"
    with open(file, 'rb') as open_file: 
        for line in open_file:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if re.search(start_string, line) :
                answer=line
                break
    start=answer.find(start_string)+len(start_string)
    end=answer.find(end_string)
    #print(start,end,answer)
    return answer[start:end]


beginstr=''
end='@'
file='test.txt'
readstring=str(get_html_string(file,beginstr,end))


print readstring
```

Comment: The `break` breaks out of the `for`-loop

Comment: Why does this code look complicated for such a simple task ? Is there one address per line in your input file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is quite big (11G) so you shouldn't keep all those strings in memory. Instead, process the file line by line and write the result before reading next line.

This should be efficient :

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('result.txt', 'w') as output_file:
       for line in input_file:
            prefix = line.split('@')[0]
            output_file.write(prefix + '\n')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you verry much!! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your file looks like this example:

```
user@google.com
user2@jshds.com
Useruser@jsnl.com
```

You can use this:

```
def get_email_name(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    result = list()
    for line in lines:
        result.append(line.split('@')[0])
    return result

get_email_name('emails.txt')
```

Out:

```
['user', 'user2', 'Useruser']
```